# How to test the content type sent by $.ajax from a sinon fake server

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, unit-testing, sinon

I have the following ajax call inside the method `loadComponent`

```
function loadComponent( url, success ) {
    $.ajax({
      accepts: "text/html"
      url: url,
      success: success
    });
}
```

How would I verify if "text/html" was passed correctly to a sinon fake server?

(Note that I am not using "accepts" correctly, so the content type will not be sent with the ajax call)

Pseudo-code below:

```
test( "testing if text/html was sent", function() {
    var server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
    loadComponent( "/url" );
    // How do I make this check ????
    ok( server.wasCalledWithContentType( "text/html" ) );
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Setting request headers with jQuery

jQuery documentation is unintuitive about usage of `accepts` parameter. Accept header is controlled by setting `dataType` parameter. If you want `text/html` set `dataType` to `html`.

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "html",
    url: "/foo"
});

Accept: text/html, */*; q=0.01
```

With `accepts`parameter you customize the content of  the header for given data type:

```
$.ajax({
    dataType: "html",
    accepts: { html: "text/foobar" },
    url: "/foo"
});

Accept: text/foobar, */*; q=0.01
```

## Testing request headers with Sinon and Jasmine

Now we have understanding on how $.ajax works. Sinon fakeserver request headers with `server.requests[0].requestHeaders`. 
Below is example test suite written with Jasmine and Sinon. For live tests check [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tuupola/puks5gam/).

```
describe("Fake server", function() {
    "use strict";

    var server;

    beforeEach(function() {
        server = sinon.fakeServer.create();
        server.autoRespond = true;

        server.respondWith("GET", "/foo",
                          [200, {"Content-Type": "application/json"},
                           '{"message":"foo"}']);
    });

    afterEach(function() {
        server.restore();
    });

    it("accept header should include text/html", function () {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "html",
            url: "/foo"
        });

        var accept = server.requests[0].requestHeaders.Accept;
        expect(accept).toMatch(/text\/html/);
    });

    it("accept header should include text/foobar", function () {
        $.ajax({
            dataType: "html",
            accepts: { html: "text/foobar" },
            url: "/foo"
        });

        var accept = server.requests[0].requestHeaders.Accept;
        expect(accept).toMatch(/text\/foobar/);
    });

});
```

Comment: I have not tested, but assuming your very good answer and rep number I am going to accept. Also, due to the fact the bounty is ending I will provide it to you because I am gonna lose it anyway. It seems in the end though that the answer is `server.requests[0].requestHeaders.Accept;`. Is that documented? I did not see it anywhere in sinon website (that worries be, cause if that is not documented it could break anytime without notice).

Comment: I just did `console.log(server)` to find what it contains. Test suite is working. I tested it before copy pasting the code to SO.

Comment: Oh, it seems to be documented too. Search for ´requestHeaders´ at  http://sinonjs.org/docs/

Comment: Well, since I am not familiarized with sinon's internals I would never get to the point of linking the fakeServer with the fakeXMLHttpRequest. In my point of view that documentation is not intuitive enough when one should inspect the implementation details to get to the point where he could be able to find the real docs.

Comment: But I think that's why stackoverflow exists right? hehe. Thanks man.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  success: function(response, status, xhr){ 
    var ct = xhr.getResponseHeader("content-type") || "";
    if (ct.indexOf('html') > -1) {
      //do something
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear I am not trying to make the code work, but to test it is failing using sinon fake server.

Answer (score 0):

This could work:

```
$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: success,
    dataType: "html"
});
```

Comment: I edited the question to make it clear I am not trying to make the code work, but to test it is failing using sinon fake server.

Comment: To test for failure I'd use .fail(function(){...}); construct

Comment: I am not testing the ajax itself, I am test the incorrect behavior for unit testing.

Comment: I think it would be more helpful for the OP and further visitors,when you add some explaination to your intension.

Answer (score 0):

Are you want verify query on server-fake-side on sinon ? May be you helps such example:

```
server.respondWith(method, model,

    (function() {

      var answer = [];

      if (model.attributes.car_model == "") {
        answer = [
          404,
          { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          '[{"0":"not car selected"}]'
        ];
      } else {
        answer = [
          200,
          { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
          '[{"0":"good query"}]'
        ];
      }

      return answer;

    })(model));
```

In this example model and models properties are verifying, but use so properties, as you want.

Answer (score 0):

Due to the lack of correct answers it seems that, up to date, there is no feature in sinon fakeServer to allow testing the mime type that was sent in the request.